# How to know which java script function is being executed in huge bulk of code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to Java script,HTML and CSS and know the basics of it. As I am working for the project I am feeling difficulty to find which java script function(code flow) is being executed,even though using console. So any tips to make it easy or any tool to find which line number being executed. Thank you.

Comment: Use alert("something"); where you want to track the function flow

Comment: You can add `break points` in your developer tools and trace the flow

Comment: you can use break points in the developer menu of the browser, console.log() or alert(). Console logs will not stop the execution, while the others will.

Comment: function myfn () {
 console.log(myfn.name)
}; // use name property to print the function name.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
alert("function was called");
```

or

```
console.log("function was called");
```

to track your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome developer tools, set the break point somewhere in the beginning  and then use Step options to jump into/out functions and track it. This url would help you: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/step-code?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the link mentioned above. I will make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, in the beginning it does take time to getting used to console/developer tools.

I would suggest to go through some tutorial of the consoles to get some insight. Here are some of the links-
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Most helpful part of these tools is the breakpoint. The function you want to know how it behaves on your website, just find that files in the source section of the dev tools. Place a breakpoint. Whenver the execution reaches the function. The debugger pauses right there and then allows you to see the execution line by line.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en

This will help you get started.